# Using widget styles from different theme

Tags: android, android-theme

Just wondering if there is an option to define a theme in the manifest that inherits from Theme.Holo and to allow some widgets to use Theme.Holo.Light based styles?

I'm aware that it's not a good practice but I have a request that requires it (i.e. using search and switch buttons from one theme and date pickers from another) but I haven't yet found a way to make it work.

Many thanks!

Comment: so no one know it? :)